# Java container overloading

Tags: java, methods, containers, overloading

I have some methods that I want to be labeled the same, and I determined using overloading to be the probable solution. The problem is, I can't do that with containers:

```
public void render(Vector2Obj<Double> display) {
    g.drawImage(sprite, display.getX().intValue(), display.getY().intValue(), null);
}

public void render(Vector2Obj<Integer> display) {
    g.drawImage(sprite,display.getX(), display.getY(), null);
}
```

The syntax error it gives me is "name clash: both methods have same erasure".

My two questions are:

1. Why won't java let me do this?
2. Is there a better solution to the than:

   ```
   public void renderD(Vector2Obj<Double> display) { //notice the name change
       g.drawImage(sprite, display.getX().intValue(), display.getY().intValue(), null);
   }

   public void renderI(Vector2Obj<Integer> display) { //notice the name change
       g.drawImage(sprite,display.getX(), display.getY(), null);
   }
   ```

   Or separating them via name?

Comment: "Or separating them via name?" what else is 2 doing?

Comment: You could have `render(int x, int y)` and `render(double x, double x)` overloads.

Comment: Nothing just changing it to renderD or renderI instead of just render

Comment: I do know I can just split it up but I want to know if I can do it with containers

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `intValue()` in the `Double` version, as opposed to rounding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explore generics with wild cards i.e. something like `Vector2Obj<? extends Number>`.

```
public void render(Vector2Obj<? extends Number> display) {
// do something by accessing methods available in Number
}
```

If your application still needs to distinguish between `int` and `double` then you can check display object if it's an instance of `Integer` or `Double` and then route it to overloaded methods `drawImage`.

Comment: Well the problem is were there is     display.getX().intValue() it doesn't know what the intValue() portion is.

Comment: Then have a single method like above with generics for all subclasses of Number and then check for instanceOf and then handle your int and double by overloading drawImage with primitives. One more option to explore is Factory Method Design Pattern for this situation.